# "Failed building wheel for py-bcrypt" when pip installing flask-user

Tags: python, visual-c++, flask

I'm trying to pip install the various extensions for Flask. So far they've all succeeded, and I've had no problems installing flask, flask-bcrypt, etc. with the exception of flask-user.

When I try to pip install flask-user, the first error I get is "Failed building wheel for py-bcrypt".

And then the following appears.

```
Failed to build py-bcrypt
Installing collected packages: py-bcrypt, pycrypto, flask-user
  Running setup.py install for py-bcrypt
    Complete output from command C:\Python27\Scripts\venv_flask\Scripts\python.e
xe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\brandon\\appdata\\local\
\temp\\pip-build-czloyh\\py-bcrypt\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'op
en', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install -
-record c:\users\brandon\appdata\local\temp\pip-nk4rxx-record\install-record.txt
 --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Python27\Scr
ipts\venv_flask\include\site\python2.7\py-bcrypt:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building 'bcrypt._bcrypt' extension
    C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Pyth
on\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include
-IC:\Python27\Scripts\venv_flask\PC /Tcbcrypt/bcrypt.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\R
elease\bcrypt/bcrypt.obj
    bcrypt.c
    bcrypt/bcrypt.c(139) : warning C4996: '_snprintf': This function or variable
 may be unsafe. Consider using _snprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
            C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++
for Python\9.0\VC\Include\stdio.h(358) : see declaration of '_snprintf'
    bcrypt/bcrypt.c(249) : warning C4996: '_snprintf': This function or variable
 may be unsafe. Consider using _snprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
            C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++
for Python\9.0\VC\Include\stdio.h(358) : see declaration of '_snprintf'
    C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Pyth
on\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include
-IC:\Python27\Scripts\venv_flask\PC /Tcbcrypt/bcrypt_pbkdf.c /Fobuild\temp.win32
-2.7\Release\bcrypt/bcrypt_pbkdf.obj
    bcrypt_pbkdf.c
    C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Pyth
on\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include
-IC:\Python27\Scripts\venv_flask\PC /Tcbcrypt/bcrypt_python.c /Fobuild\temp.win3
2-2.7\Release\bcrypt/bcrypt_python.obj
    bcrypt_python.c
    bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c(63) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'lo
ng' to 'u_int8_t', possible loss of data
    C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Pyth
on\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include
-IC:\Python27\Scripts\venv_flask\PC /Tcbcrypt/blowfish.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7
\Release\bcrypt/blowfish.obj
    blowfish.c
    c:\users\brandon\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-czloyh\py-bcrypt\bcrypt\pybc_b
lf.h(86) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'passlen'
    c:\users\brandon\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-czloyh\py-bcrypt\bcrypt\pybc_b
lf.h(86) : error C2081: 'size_t' : name in formal parameter list illegal
    c:\users\brandon\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-czloyh\py-bcrypt\bcrypt\pybc_b
lf.h(86) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'passlen'
    c:\users\brandon\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-czloyh\py-bcrypt\bcrypt\pybc_b
lf.h(86) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
    c:\users\brandon\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-czloyh\py-bcrypt\bcrypt\pybc_b
lf.h(86) : error C2059: syntax error : ','
    c:\users\brandon\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-czloyh\py-bcrypt\bcrypt\pybc_b
lf.h(88) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    c:\users\brandon\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-czloyh\py-bcrypt\bcrypt\pybc_b
lf.h(91) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'n'
    c:\users\brandon\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-czloyh\py-bcrypt\bcrypt\pybc_b
lf.h(91) : error C2081: 'size_t' : name in formal parameter list illegal
    c:\users\brandon\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-czloyh\py-bcrypt\bcrypt\pybc_b
lf.h(91) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'n'
    c:\users\brandon\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-czloyh\py-bcrypt\bcrypt\pybc_b
lf.h(91) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
    c:\users\brandon\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-czloyh\py-bcrypt\bcrypt\pybc_b
lf.h(91) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Brandon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Micros
oft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I didn't want to risk leaving anything out. However, I BELIEVE the key part of this error message is this part:

```
    bcrypt/bcrypt.c(139) : warning C4996: '_snprintf': This function or variable
 may be unsafe. Consider using _snprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
```

I believe that there is something with Microsoft Visual Basic that's the problem. However, I haven't gotten any good answers online when I looked it up. I'm using Microsoft Visual Basic C++ 's compiler for Python 2.7

I haven't seen any other problems online that seem to address my problem. Some come close, but they seem to offer solutions that don't have anything to do with my problem (references to files that I don't use/have, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to install python-dev for your python version.

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with Microsoft Visual Studio which seems to be patched now. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/py-bcrypt/issues/detail?id=15) the patch.

Comment: I installed that already. It doesn't seem to work if you're trying to install in a virtualenv, though.